# How to switch between buttons after a specific time interval?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating an android app(am a beginner) where in the phone dialer screen, the buttons have to be highlighted one by one after a given time interval sequentially.I am using Android Studio.

Thanks in Advance.:)

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion is either using [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) or [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html):

```
new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // paint the button x
    }
}, 5000);
```

Or using

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
@Override
public void run(){
      // paint the button x
   }
}, 0, 5000);
```